# How to suppress spaces in labels?

Tags: qgis, labeling

I want to label some lines. The labels has spaces like "label 1". I want to suppress all spaces so that the result is like "label2" without changing the attribute table. Is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use expression-base labeling and just replace the space  with nothing

```
replace("label",' ','')
```